# Files disappear from Launcher

Tags: unity, nautilus, files

I tried to solve this 'cause I'm not the only one with this problem, but still I can't get rid of it.

The problem is like in this gif:

[image]

BUT I saw that if I open nautilus using ALT+F2, it doesn't disappear.
Why is that?

Comment: there's a bug reported here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1565194

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that nautilus itself is always running in the background. If you start a new nautilus instance, it will just "attach" to the previously running instance of nautilus, then close itself. That is why it is disappearing from the launcher.

Try opening nautilus with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> like you said, right click it, then hit "Lock to Launcher".

This should make it so that it won't disappear from the launcher, but it will also stay there the entire time.

You can also `killall nautilus` then try opening it from the launcher. Since there are no longer any more instances when you start it, it should stay open.

Comment: Is there a way to keep nautilus from "attaching" itself to the previous instance? The are many times when I would like to have more than one nautilus window open.

Comment: @EricPower It doesn't look like you can do this normally. If you have the window in the sidebar, you can right-click and select "Open a New Window" option. This will still attach it to the current nautilus daemon, but you can definitely have more than one window open at a time.
Try opening nautilus more than once from the dash, it should create a new window every time.

Answer (score 1):

workaround in [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321285&p=13487098#post13487098) worked for me

> I went to /usr/share/applications and took a backup of
>   nautilus.desktop and org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
>
> Then:
>
> - In nautilus.desktop, removed "NotShowIn=Unity;"
> - In org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop, added "NotShowIn=Unity;" and removed
>     "OnlyShowIn=Unity;"